# converting Latin characters to Hebrew encoding

Tags: c#, winforms, encoding, hebrew

I have asked this question before and got my answer. 
But now I am facing a different problem.
I have a file name. The name is: ‹˜ˆ‘ ‡™……
I want to decode it in order to get the Hebrew value of it.
The code I used:

```
 Encoding latinEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252");
 Encoding hebrewEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(862);
 byte[] latinBytes = latinEncoding.GetBytes(str);
 string hebrewString = hebrewEncoding.GetString(latinBytes);
```

This code works good but not great. I mean that few characters are decoded to "?" instead of their Hebrew value.

So decoding the given name with this code gives me: "כרטס? חשבונו?" instead of "כרטסת חשבונות".
the Hebrew characters that have that problem are: ך,ל,מ,ת.
All others are decoded great.

I found a solution but I would like to avoid it if possible.
The solution was saving the given string to a file and then read the file back with 862 encoding.
The code is:

```
string str = "‹˜ˆ‘ ‡™……";

// Get uniqe file name based on current date and time
reportFileName = DateTime.Now.ToString().Replace("/", "-").Replace(":", ";");

// set the file path
string repFilePath = parametersFolder + @"\" + reportFileName;

// save the value to a file with 1255 encoding
File.WriteAllText(repFilePath, str, Encoding.GetEncoding(1255));

// read the value back with 862 encoding
string s = File.ReadAllText(repFilePath, Encoding.GetEncoding(862));

// Delete the file
File.Delete(repFilePath);

// Save the value to a variable.
generatedFileName = s;
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: @JohnSaunders Ok, I'll remember that for next time. What about an answer to my question? Do you have one?

Comment: Are you sure that the name should be **‹˜ˆ‘ ‡™……** ? I receive the correct result with the name **‹˜ˆ‘š ‡™……š**. Besides, your workaround doesn't work at all on my computer because of an exception in the line with Substring.

Comment: @MichałKomorowski Yes. I copy-pasted it.
Regarding my solution, I updated my answer.
Just remove that line of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. For some reason it works now but I am positive that I have tried it before posting the question and it didn't work.

```
Encoding latinEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1255");
Encoding hebrewEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(862);
byte[] latinBytes = latinEncoding.GetBytes(str);
string hebrewString = hebrewEncoding.GetString(latinBytes);
```

Read the string as 1255 encoding instead of 1252 encoding.